# A weakly sequentially continuous operator which is not weakly continuous

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, counterexamples, continuity

I'm reading some papers where the condition of weak sequential continuity is crucial instead of the weak continuity.

So, let

- $T$ an operator between a Banach space $X$ and itself.

1. $T$ is **weakly sequentially continuous** if for any $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, $x_n \stackrel{w}{\rightharpoonup}x$ in $X$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(x_n) \stackrel{w}{\rightharpoonup } T( x )$ in $X$)*.
2. $T$ is **weakly continuous** iff $T$ is continuous with respect to the weak topologies on $X$

While it is clear that 2 implies 1, I want to find a counter-example of an operator which verifies 1 but not 2.

**$T$ is not linear**

Comment: Both assertions are equivalent, and they are also equivalent to "3. $T$ is norm continuous". Proof: "3. => 2." This follows from the existence of the dual operator. "2. => 1." As mentioned in the question, this is obvious. "1. => 3": Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ which converges to $0$ in norm. Then $(x_n)$ converges also weakly to $0$. Hence, $(Tx_n)$ converges weakly to $0$ by 1. Thus, $(Tx_n)$ is bounded by the uniform boundedness principle. So $T$ maps sequencs that norm converge to $0$ to bounded sequences; this is sufficient for norm continuity of $T$.

Comment: I added the "Banach spaces" tag. By the way, what does the symbol "$)^*$" mean at the end of assertion 1.?

Comment: $T$ is not linear

Comment: Then just use some fancy space $X$ like $\ell^1$ in which the weak convergence (of sequences) is equivalent to the norm convergence but the weak topology is substantially different from the norm one. For the operator, just take $Tx=\|x\|e$ where $e$ is any non-zero vector in $X$.