# Weak sequential continuity vs strong continuity

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, continuity

Let $E$ be a Banach space, $T:E\rightarrow E$ a non-linear operator.

$T$ is said to be **Weakly Sequentially Continuous (shortly W.S.C)** on $E,$ if for every $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n}\subseteq E$ with $x_{n} \rightharpoonup  x,$ we have $T x_{n} \rightharpoonup  T x$.

> In papers they use this type of continuity because, *"although it is not always possible to show that a given mapping between functional Banach
> spaces is weakly continuous, quite often its weak sequential continuity can be checked easily.
> This follows, among other things, from the fact that Lebesgue’s dominated convergence theorem
> is valid for sequences but it fails for nets"*.

I have some questions here about **strong continuity (in the strong topology)** and **W.S.C**,

1. In a Banach space, which one implies the other one (if there is an implication between them)? If there are some examples, I will be very grateful
2. Let's suppose that I am working under the weak topology and I have a result that works for both strong continuity **or** W.S.C, which one is more interesting to choose?

Comment: I assume that $T$ is allowed to be non-linear again, as in [your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/372401/102946)? If yes, then I suggest to replace "an operator" in your first sentence either with "an (in general, non-linear) operator" or with "a mapping".

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this.

Comment: It is easy to show that a Banach space is a Shur space (every weakly convergent sequence is norm convergent) if and only if the norm is weakly sequentially continuous. Hint: Show that in every non Shur space there is a sequence of unit vectors that converges weakly to zero.